# Is there a limit to the number of different antibodies one individual can have in their body?

Tags: antibodies

If my understanding is correct, we create antibodies after vaccines and after getting infections. So, after 10 vaccines and 2 contracted diseases, I can have in my body antibodies for 12 types of diseases.

Is there a limit to the number of different antibody types that we can have in the body at one point?

Also, do we spend resources keeping those numbers up when the antibodies are not used?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you done any reading about this? What did you learn? For example, did you read about Immunological memory?

Comment: I haven't done any reading, and I wasn't able to find anything on it. I think I didn't exactly know how to search for it. Thank you for bringing up immunological memory. I'll try searching along that path.